# Nuxt 3 – Best way to render ssr page immediatly and fill with fetched content after it is ready

Tags: nuxt.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

What is the best way to render my SSR nuxt 3 app instantly (all the layouts and nav) and display content fetched from an API only when it is ready? For example, display placeholder / skelleton content while pending, and replace it with the actual data after fetch resolved?

Currently I am doing it with the {server: false} option in useFetch, and using the useFetch's "pending" property to check if content is ready. Is that the common way / best practice to do it?

Thanks,
– Simon

Answer (score 0):

You could define a main function called `initialize()`, put into it all the calls related to the data you want to fetch once the app is ready, and then call the function on the `onMounted()` event. Doing so will be more like Vue.js, since you are not using SSR.

You could also try the new Vue 3 `<Suspense>` feature.
https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html

Comment: I would suggest to use <Suspense>